How to configure client side Spring Cloud Config backed with AWS Parameter Store
I am trying to load configurations from AWS Parameter Store ("/application/foo") so that I can dynamically set the configurations at runtime. I've used Spring Cloud Config Consul prior but not sure what's the setup for AWS Parameter Store.
Dependencies:

Spring Boot 3.1.1
Java 17
Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.4

io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter:3.0.4
io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-parameter-store:3.0.4
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:4.0.4
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.6

application.yaml
spring.config.import: "optional:aws-parameterstore:/application/foo

When I run with aws-parameterstore, I get the following error:

The spring.config.import property is missing a configserver: entry
Action:
Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.
If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional.configserver: instead.

I tried adding below
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.0.4

Now I am getting

Config data resource '[ParameterStoreConfigDataResource@... context="/application/foo', optional=false]' via location 'aws-parameterstore:/application/foo' does not exist.

What gives?

Do you want to use config server or AWS parameter store directly? Your spring.config.import is the latter and config server is not needed in that case

@spencergibb I want to use AWS parameter store directly. Are you saying I only need spring.config.import? For some reason, even though I have a predefined "application/foo" in AWS paramstore, it's not loading such configurations at startup from the app side. And I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Config server is not needed then. I don't use or maintain spring cloud aws, so I can't help there
